# How to retreive an image from drawable folder?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to display an image from a drawable but instead it is outputting a set of string an integers instead. I have saved the image as an png file.

```
  Drawable yellowSmileyFace = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.happy_yellow_small);


  if (getClickCountInt == 4){
   ShowRewardDialog("Test" +  "\n\n" + yellowSmileyFace);
```

This is what it is outputting currently: android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@15712cc6

Comment: What you want to achieve?

Comment: To actually display the image itself

Comment: Show why you are not passing Drawable object itself

Comment: @Jarvis I'm sorry I am a little confused by your last comment. Maybe that's what I am getting wrong. Are you saying pass the drawable object to get the image? If so what is the syntax for that?